# I don't understand how the coefficients for the Givens rotation matrix have been coded here

Tags: algorithm, matrix, fortran, eigenvalue

I found this fortran90 code for finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix using the Jacobi algorithm. I understand the general concept but, there are 3-4 lines that I don't understand.

Here is a piece of the code :

```
1   do while (b2.gt.abserr)
2    do i=1,n-1
3    do j=i+1,n
4       if (a(j,i)**2 <= bar) cycle  ! do not touch small elements
5        b2 = b2 - 2.0*a(j,i)**2
6        bar = 0.5*b2/float(n*n)
7    ! calculate coefficient c and s for Givens matrix
8        beta = (a(j,j)-a(i,i))/(2.0*a(j,i))
9        coeff = 0.5*beta/sqrt(1.0+beta**2)
10        s = sqrt(max(0.5+coeff,0.0))
11        c = sqrt(max(0.5-coeff,0.0))
```

So, `b2` is defined as the sum of the squares of the off–diagonal entries; `abserr` is the threshold for the precision; `bar` is another threshold in order to take the biggest entry in absolute value we want to zeroed and `a(i,j)` are the entries of the initial matrix.

What I don't understand would be the line **9**,***10*** and ***11***. In every courses, videos, pdf and so on, I have read or watched, the coefficient `coeff` here ( **t** most of time) is never defined like this. Instead, it is defined like `t = 1.0/(abs(beta) + sqrt(beta**2 + 1.0))` and if `beta` is negative then `t = -t`. And therefore, I'm also not sure about lines ***10*** and ***11*** since the values of `c` and `s` are related to `beta`.

If anyone knows the Jacobi eigenvalue method for symmetric matrix and understand the code above, I would highly appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Sit down an check the math. You should find that it is equivalent. `s+c` is probably an absolute value.

Comment: Well, the thing is, without the factor 0.5, I found the equation for `coeff` in the code for `s`. And `c` is `c = s*t`. So i'm a bit confused on how `coeff`, `s` and `c` are defined here. Maybe I'm missing something or I just don't understand very well the method in general. Thanks for the help.